# Two django projects sharing the same database user tables

Tags: python, django

I have tried to find the answer to my question and I couldn't so I am giving it a go.

My problem is that I want to use the same users-related tables (`auth_*`, `account_userprofile`, `account_userpermissions`) on two completely different projects.

I have read the [sites framework documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/) but still my questions are unanswered.

I don't understand how to share the aforementioned models (existing in `project_1/account/models.py`).

Should I copy `project_1/account/models.py` to `project_2/account/models.py` and fake project_2 `account` migrations?

What if want to change a field in `account_userprofile` model? Would I need to make the modifications in both `models.py` copies and fake project_2's migration? Isn't this ugly?

I am sure there is something that I am terribly missing here. What is the proper/best way to use the same user-related tables between two different projects?

PS: Using python 3, django 2.0, PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: If this is about a larger project, and the prospect is a also a larger user base, you might want to think about setting up an OAUTH2 server which serves both of the applications as a social login provider. You could do this probably quite quickly via django-oauth-toolkit for the OAUTH2 server and a custom provider based on django-allauth in both the dependent applications.

Comment: Thanks. I have considered this. But I'd prefer to learn how to share database tables between projects. Because there is a chance that I am asked to share other tables than user-related.